# Selectively composing beans from external xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am currently using a import tag to import bean definition from external file.

```
<import resource="resources/messageSource.xml"/>
```

Is there a way to selectively pick a bean definition from external file. Or a way to remove imported bean.

i.e let say messageSource.xml has multiple beans (bean1, bean2.... bean10) can we explicitly remove one of the bean (e.g.. bean1) while importing so that after we import we only have 9 beans i.e (bean2, bean3...bean10)

One way I could think of doing this is by using profiles but that would require changing the external file. Can there be a way to achieve this without changing the external file?

**Update1:**
Reason for trying to achieve this is to avoid redundancy and decrease the number of touchpoint in future if something needs to be changed.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Please give your reason.

Comment: Because I don't want to copy paste the existing config. Also it increases the touchpoints if something needs to be fixed or updated.

Comment: You don't copy/paste if you import your configuration. I just can't see why declaring beans if we do not need them. You have the possibility to declare `lazily` your beans so they are not picked up since you call them explicitly.